# Why are ACLs not loading on ec2 instance from saved image?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-9.10, access-control-list

I am doing a nightly backup of an Ubuntu (9.10) server instance I have running on Amazon's EC2. This morning I started a new instance from the most recent saved image. When I ssh into the instance created from the image the ACLs I created on the original instance are not in place.

The acl option is working on the mounted drive and I can run `setfacl` and `getfacl` fine on the folders but the permissions returned from getfacl are not the same between the instances.

The mostly likely reason for this I suppose is that wherever the acl permissions are stored doesn't get copied as part of `ec2-bundle-vol` but I don't know where the acls are stored and so I don't know how to copy and restore them on the newly created instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ec2-bundle-vol does not appear to pass the -A option to rsync when it's building the bundle.  You'll need to add this to the source so that ACLs are copied.

Try changing '-rlpgoD' to '-rlpgoDA' in a file named something like /usr/lib/ec2-ami-tools/lib/ec2/platform/linux/rsync.rb (though it could have been installed in a completely different directory, depending on your distro).

Comment: Ha, I just saw your post on the AWS forums as well. Is using ACLs really that unusual?

Comment: Also, it looks like this should absolutely work. I didn't really think to go digging in the source of the tools too look for an answer. Thank you.